# Can't receive multicast packets outside of sending host

Tags: c++, c, sockets, multicast

I have an application that regularly receives multicast updates from another application. As long as the receiver application is on the same host as the sender, I am able to get the multicast packets. If the receiver application is another host in the same LAN, then I am unable to read the multicast packets. I can see the those packets on wireshark on both machines.

```
Host A [Win8.1]- Both Wireshark and my app can read the packets.
Host B [Win2012 R2] - Only Wireshark can see the packets, my app reads nothing.
```

The sender is on Host A. The Host A also has Hyper-V enabled, if that matters.

My app uses Boost.asio sockets, I am seeing the same results using C sockets too. Here is the C example with all the error handling stripped off for simplicity. It works only on Host A, but not on Host B.

**EDIT:** I tried something crazy today.

I started the same sender on Host B using the same MC address and port. Now the receiver started receiving transmissions from both Host A and B. Then I shutdown the sender on Host B, but the receiver continued to receive packets from Host A. Now I restarted the receiver on Host B, it is again blind as a bat.

```
void Receiver(const char* mc_address, short port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int addrlen, sock;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    char message[500];

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&addr,0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mc_address);         
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;         
    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(const char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)); 

    while (1) 
    {
        int count = recvfrom(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
        if (count == 0) break;
        message[count] = 0;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you analyze what `bind`, `socket`, `setsockopt` functions return?

Comment: None of them return any errors, that is why I stripped them off while posting here. I am hoping I have missed some socket option I need to set.

Comment: Does tcpdump show the multicast packet arriving? Might it be that your switch is pruning multicast?

Comment: Wireshark on Host B is showing the multicast packets, that would be same as tcpdump, isn't it?

Comment: Is it possible a firewall on the receiving host is preventing the packets from reaching your app?  Wireshark might be running the NIC in promiscuous mode so it will see packets that the network stack will reject.

Comment: No, I have disabled windows firewall on both hosts.

Comment: If I reverse the sender and receiver, that sender on Host B and receiver on Host A, it works. Looks like something to do with routing tables. But I am not good at messing around with routing tables.

Comment: If you have multiple NICs in the machine where the app does not receive the multicast traffic, try setting the interface metrics. See also [An explanation of the Automatic Metric feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299540) and [How to change the binding order of network adapters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894564)